# Spivak's Calculus - Chapter 1 Question 4.12

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-writing

In Spivak's Calculus Fourth Edition, Chapter 1 Question 4.12:

> Find all numbers $x$ for which $x + 3^x < 4$

Using only the following properties:

[image]
[image]

I can see that $x + 3 = 4 \to x = 1$. So, $x$ should be less than one.

But, I'm not really sure how Spivak--or any other good teacher--would write this out formally using the properties above.

Any hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The functions $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 3^x$ are both strictly increasing. Therefore, so is their sum $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$. Therefore, $h(x) < h(1) = 4$ if and only if $x < 1$. That seems like the natural proof to me. I don't know how you would prove it directly using only P1-P12 above. Has Spivak even defined $3^x$ for arbitrary real values of $x$, in chapter 1?

Comment: @Bungo - Nope. Chapter one gets a little harry pretty quickly with exponents.

Comment: I just reviewed chapter 1. I don't think Spivak is being fair with this question (and with the preceding part xi, $2^x < 8$). Not only has he not defined $3^x$, it's actually not possible to do so (assuming $x$ is an arbitrary real number) on the basis of properties P1-P12. Indeed, a system of numbers satisfying P1-P12 need not include every real number. For example, the set of rational numbers satisfies P1-P12. An additional property/axiom is needed, namely that the real numbers are **complete**. He alludes to this in the last few sentences of the chapter.

Comment: And as he mentions, it will require all of parts I and II of the book in order to even define what that means. And without it, he can't define $3^x$ for irrational values of $x$!

Comment: If I were assigned this problem, I would point this out in my solution, and I would indicate that I will make the further (true but yet unprovable) assumption that $3^x < 3^y$ if and only if $x < y$. (i.e. the function $g(x) = 3^x$ is strictly increasing)

Comment: Thank you! I thought that might be the case. Best!

Comment: The problem I see, is that if you can only use the axioms listed, it doesn't seem that "$<$" has been defined.  Don't we need some axioms of inequality to go with this?  And, then has $3^x$ been defined?

Comment: @DougM - There are a few axioms related to inequalities in the chapter. ( They are meant to be implied by P10 - P12 ) Though, that's not at all obvious without having recently read the chapter, I'd say.

Comment: @DougM Although not listed explicitly in these properties, Spivak has already defined $a < b$ to mean $b-a \in P$ (the set of positive numbers).